# Set content settings from Chrome extension background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to allow Adobe Flash Player on an extension when the user clicks a button. I have most of the code done, but I get an error.

Here is the current code I have:

```
console.log("First time install detected. Prompting about Flash Player.");
if (window.confirm("Enable Flash Player?"))
{
chrome.contentSettings['adobe-flash-player'].set({
primaryPattern: 'chrome-extension://~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~',
setting: details.setting == 'allow'
})
}else{
console.log("Flash player prompt denied.")
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined at background.js:5
```

In my manifest I have content-settings in the permissions, but I cannot figure out what I did one. Can anyone help?

Comment: The error tells you there's no 'adobe-flash-player' in chrome.contentSettings. See https://crbug.com/695092 for details and an example of correct code.

Comment: Problem fixed. Thank you WOxxOm.